# runtime error when trying to read data from file

Tags: c, file, structure, runtime-error

I have a question on logical error, the error was

"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'list' was corrupted."

there are a total of 60 lines in the in.txt file

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILE_NAME  20
#define LIST_SIZE 50
//void getData(RECORD name[], RECORD score)


typedef struct 
{
    char *name;
    int  score;
}RECORD;


int main (void)
{
    // Declarations
       FILE *fp;
       char fileName[FILE_NAME];
       RECORD list[LIST_SIZE];
       char buffer[100];
       int count = 0;
       int i;
    // Statements
       printf("Enter the file name: ");
       gets(fileName);

       fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

       if(fp == NULL)
      printf("Error cannot open the file!\n");
       while(fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
         {  
         list[count].name = (char*) calloc(strlen(buffer), sizeof(RECORD*));
         if(count > 50)
         {

         }

         if( count < 50)
         {
            sscanf(buffer,"%[^,], %d", list[count].name, &list[count].score);
            for( i =1; i < (50 - count); i++)
            {   
                list[count + i].name = 0;
                list[count + i].score = 0;
            }
         }
         count++;

     }

       printf("Read in %d data records\n", count);
       fclose(fp);
       return 0;
}
```

in this program I' m trying to read data from file to array of structures, so if the number of data is less than 50, structures that don't have data will be zero out and if the number of data is more than 50 the program will only read the first 50 structures.

how can i fix the runtime error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Perhaps...

while(fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
{
  if( count >= 50)
  {
     break;
  }
  if( count < 50)
  {
     list[count].name = (char*) malloc(strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char));
     sscanf(buffer,"%[^,], %d", list[count].name, &list[count].score);
     count++;
  }
}
for( i =0; i < (50 - count); i++)
{   
    list[count + i].name = 0;
    list[count + i].score = 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the for loop should be outside of the while loop since count will always be zero

Comment: @user1763658 this should stop at `break`

Comment: @user1763658 `count`'re counting up when the input is.

Comment: i got it to work now the for loop need to be inside while loop

Comment: for the step of empty out the structures that don't have data, then wouldn't it empty structures from 0 to 49 if it is outside the while loop?

Comment: I think should be in the outside of the input loop `for loop` is, because I wonder is if you do not reach the specified number after the input is completed.

Comment: let say if i only get to 30 lines then the count would be 30 and the count + i would go from 30 to 49 and that is the data that i would want to empty out. actually i think to set i equal 1 instead of 0

Comment: Advise: `50` replace  to `LIST_SIZE` is better.

Comment: count is count up after input. So 1 RECORD input, count == 1. LIST[0] has data. LIST[1] hasn't data. because not 1.

Comment: if 30 RECORD input then count == 30, LIST[29] is LAST input RECORD.  LIST[count + i] = zero , if i = 1 then skip LIST[30].

Answer (score 0):

What if count = 50?

Try with the following in your while loop bringing if block in the start or at the end;

```
if(count >= 50) //count should be checked for >= 50 before being used.
{

}
list[count].name = (char*) calloc(strlen(buffer), sizeof(RECORD*)); //list size is 50 so list[50] won't work. out of bound.
```

Comment: it is still showing the same error, also why would i check for count >= to 50 since i only want 50 lines of data so count should go from 0 to 49

Comment: can you update your code in the question with what updates you made?

Comment: what are you doing in if block when count > = 50?